# Liesubgroups given by representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Maybe it's a little odd question, but I encountered a classification of homogeneous spaces, and I'm stuck with the following description (c.f. Onishchick, "Topology of transitive transformation groups", p. 264):

> [...]; $(SO_6,A_1^{10})$, where $A_1^{10}$ is the subgroup of type $A_1$ given by the representation $\rho(4\pi_1)$; [...].

Obviously, $SO_6/\rho(4\pi_1)(A_1)$ does not work for dimensional reasons and $\rho(G)/\rho(H)$ is the same as $G/H$ for faithful representations. Sadly, I can't find any further explanations on this. Does anybody knows how to interpretate this or can provide a reference?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what your question is. Could you provide a few more details please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basicly, I don't understand the notation. What I want is $SO_6/A_1^{10}$. If $\rho$ was the defining representation, then $\rho(A_1)=SO_2$, and we would get $SO_6/SO_2$. Sadly, I don't know it means, if $\rho$ is any other irreducible representation. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @StephanMeier Could you provide the chapter and section numbers where this sentence occurs in the book (I have a copy of the Russian edition, so the page numbers are different)? My first reaction would be to interpret $\rho(4\pi_1)$ as the irreducible complex representation of $A_1$ with highest weight $4\pi_1$, which is $\operatorname{Sym}^4(\mathbb{C}^2)$, of dimension 5. If this is true, the superscript 10 in the notation $A_1^{10}$ might refer to the real dimension of the representation. It also isn't clear whether $\operatorname{SO}_6$ refers to the complex group, or to its compact form.

Comment: It's in chapter 18 ("Homogeneous spaces of rank 1 or 2"), section 2 ("The list of all homogeneous spaces of rank 1"), in the proof of Theorem 1 (item (ii) in the proof). Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: In the Russian edition, it says $(\operatorname{SO}_5,A_1^{10})$, not $(\operatorname{SO}_6,A_1^{10})$. My interpretation of $\rho(4\pi_1)$ agrees with the book. All groups considered are compact. The superscript 10 in $A_1^{10}$ denotes the index of the homomorphism $A_1\to\operatorname{SO}_6$, which is defined in chapter 3, section 10. (to be continued)

Comment: Since $4\pi_1$ is a weight of the adjoint group $\operatorname{SO}_3$ of type $A_1$, I think that $\rho=\rho(4\pi_1)$ should be interpreted as the representation of $\operatorname{SO}_3$ on the space of harmonic homogenous polynomials in 3 variables of degree 2, with complex coefficients. Those polynomials which have real coefficients form a 5-dimensional real subspace on which $\operatorname{SO}_3$ acts irreducibly. Since $\operatorname{SO}_3$ is compact, this representation carries an invariant inner product, so we have a homomorphism $\rho : \operatorname{SO}_3\to\operatorname{SO}_5$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanations helped me a lot. And it's indeed $SO_5$ (and of course $A_1$ is $SO_3$) - sorry for that!